# How do I listen for new chat messages in text channels using a discord bot in python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've designed a system to loop through all the channels and check to see if the last few messages are the same as they were at the previous check, but that's slow and unnecessary. If there's any way to do it through a function, or a simpler, faster way, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any code? It's good to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the event `on_message`, which is called every time someone writes anything in a channel your bot can read:

```py
@bot.event #could be client.event for you
async def on_message(message):
    #do stuff here you want to do every time a new message is sent
```

---

**References:**

- [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message)